# Help with adding outlet to middle of run; new outlet not powered

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

(Preface: I have read all of the related, earlier questions I can find... still stumped.)

I added an outlet to a run by cutting (before Outlet A) what I **thought** I had identified as the line in to Outlet A, and adding a Romex pigtail to the new outlet (Outlet N).

With breaker back ON:

1. Outlet A is powered and fine.
2. Outlet N is NOT powered.
3. Outlets B and C (down run from Outlet A) are NOT powered.

What did I do wrong? Did I add the pigtail to the wrong wire? If the answer is YES, wrong wire, I did my best to ID the line coming into Outlet A; what is the trick I missed?

Additional info: House built in 2003; breakers are identified in box, but IMO oddly organized (example: "kitchen outlets" turns out to include random outlets in living room);

Thank you!

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: a **cable** contains several **wires** within a sheath.  Each wire is a different color.  When a cable is involved, I would not call it a pigtail, I would call it an extension.  It would be clearer if you could [edit] to make sure you are using the appropriate words, you can also add a photo the same way.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved?

Comment: THANKS to all who kindly suggested clarifying edits and pics; I will get this done later today.